# Ubuntu Developer Video Tutorial

Tags: application-development, programming, sdk

I am Visual Studio .net developer.

I like to check out "Ubuntu Developer Video Tutorials" for programmer and I want to develop application like VB.net Desktop application(Standalone or Web).

Is there any program like Visual Studio For Ubuntu for desktop and web application?

And which programming language I need to learn in order to develop application for Ubuntu.

Comment: http://developer.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ubuntu SDK](http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/create/get-the-sdk/) and [quickly](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tools/quickly/)

Do you need more?

Answer (score 0):

You might find this video useful: [Creating Your First Ubuntu App](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sO8hiPreNBg). Enjoy!